# Type Narrowing Not Working On Parent Object

Tags: typescript

I have this code sample:

```
type Dog = {
  legs?: number;
};

function printDogLegs(dog: Dog) {
  if (dog.legs !== undefined) {
    printConfirmedDog(dog);
  }
}

type ConfirmedDogWithLegs = {
  legs: number;
};

function printConfirmedDog(input: ConfirmedDogWithLegs) {
  console.log(input);
}
```

Despite the typeguard, I get this error from the TypeScript compiler:

```
TS2345: Argument of type 'Dog' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ConfirmedDogWithLegs'.
  Types of property 'legs' are incompatible.
    Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'.
    212 | function printDogLegs(dog: Dog) {
    213 |   if (dog.legs !== undefined) {
  > 214 |     printConfirmedDog(dog);
        |                       ^^^
    215 |   }
    216 | }
    217 |
```

I would expect TS to narrow the type of `Dog` from `legs: number | undefined` to `legs: number`. Why is this not the case? And how should I go about solving this problem?

Comment: "Why is this not the case? And how should I go about solving this problem?" is technically two questions.  Which one do you consider primary?

Comment: @jcalz As pointed out by lepsch in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73347473/4381150), Type Predicates are a way to solve this problem. However this seems a little too much work for something (IMO) very simple.

Additional explanation about why Type Predicates are necessary, and why typescript doesn't do it automatically would be helpful. Please let me know if you think this would be better asked in a separate question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is that `if (dog.legs !== undefined)` doesn't infer that `dog` is of another type, but that `dog.legs` is just `number` (without `undefined`). It continues to be of type `Dog`.

That's why [Type Predicates](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) exist in the first place. A `Type Predicate` function would solve this by narrowing the object type to something else. It would be like the following:

```js
function isDogWithLegs(dog: Dog): dog is ConfirmedDogWithLegs {
  return dog.legs !== undefined
}
```

and the check is going to be like this:

```js
function printDogLegs(dog: Dog) {
  if (isDogWithLegs(dog)) {
    printConfirmedDog(dog);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Type Predicates seem a little too complicated (having to declare a predicate for every use case) for a pretty simple problem.

Why can't typescript simply infer (as with typeguards), that legs are now defined?

I think I am missing some nuance here, and some additional explanation here would be great!

Comment: I've edited the answer with some explanation

Comment: The "why is it like this" question is essentially answered with "it is a missing feature", requested in https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384 , and there are links in there to previous issues where it's essentially considered a design limitation.