# Why does type narrowing not work with a top-level object?

Tags: typescript, interface, type-narrowing

The following code snippet contains 2 examples that seem equivalent to me, but one of them compiles while the other doesn't.

```
type PartialPerson = { firstName?: string };
type RequiredPerson = { firstName: string };

function example(myVar: PartialPerson) {
  if (myVar.firstName) {
      const compiles: RequiredPerson = { firstName: myVar.firstName } // compiles
      const doesNotCompile: RequiredPerson = myVar;                   // Does not compile
  }
}
```

You can find a Playground [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgJ2ASzgGxhBBnA9gOygF4oBvKAM2R2ADk4BbCAfgC4ptgFl8BzKAL4BuAFChIUAEoQAjgFdqEACaYcBYmUrVO9Ju07c%20g0QGMCnKAxAA1RO3JUaulvq49eAjQ%2011GEdgDkAFJwANYQAcYiyBRQABRWtggAdI46fgCUZCJQuVBm%20Bb4iAi4AO7KAMK4DGDIaBDY7NLyiipYeIQk3k5%207ImIqT7OglAA9GP5NXUN2Dl5BUUl5coAIriNtLjA1bX1-lKyCgjKqp0aAwhCeTe3d%20OT641Q%20NtTew0iAkA)

I would expect these examples to be equivalent.

I understand that the Typescript compiler fails on the 2nd example because it does not type narrow `myVar`, but my question is why? Is this an oversight in the Typescript implementation or is there a reason I'm missing here?

To be clear, this question was answered from the viewpoint of "why it doesn't compile". ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73346962/type-narrowing-not-working-on-parent-object)) I'm asking why the language is designed in this way.

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
@jcalz gave the correct answer in a comment. This is an open feature request that's mainly not done because of performance considerations.
Details [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384)

Comment: It's a missing feature, see [ms/TS#42384](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42384). Traditionally the answer for why was "it would be too expensive to synthesize new types for every object in the whole chain", but at this point it's sitting as an open feature request. See the linked questions for more info

Comment: @jcalz Thank you! That's a very relevant link that I couldn't find in my searches. Can I mark your comment as a correct answer somehow?